# Java script how to make a confirm dialog?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, django, dialog

I am writting app using Django. I don't want to make a new template, but I want to make sure if user really want to delete this element.

I just use href to go to view, delete element and I then go back do the current one. Is there any simple way to do this dialog or should I do everything with Django?

I am using this code to redirect to delete element.

```
            <td><a class="button icon remove" href="delete/{{ item.id }}" role="button" value={{ item.id }}>Delete</a>
```

Comment: jQuery UI has dialogs where you can add buttons. You can add two (and even more) buttons, one for Confirm and one for cancel. http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Bootbox.js](http://bootboxjs.com/). It gives you nice bootstrap message boxes, i.e alert, confirm and prompt.

Sample code:

```
bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {
  Example.show("Confirm result: "+result);
});
```

Comment: That looks nice. How should I use it? Wrap in <script></script>? What add to href?

Comment: href can be like this: `href='javascript:deleteItem(itemId)'`, where `deleteItem` can be a function in script tag, where you can write your code

Comment: I've added to href: onclick="myFunction({{ item.id }});"  and add your code:       `            <script>
                            function myFunction(id) {
                                bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {
                                Example.show("Confirm result: "+result);
                                });

                            }
                        </script>`  But id still doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

Use below code, which is working fine for me

```
 <td><a class="button icon remove" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" href="delete/{{ item.id }}" role="button" value={{ item.id }}>Delete</a>
```

Comment: +1 as I was also typing this. But it will still redirect, which doesn't seem to be desired behaviour, The reason I cancelled my answer :P

Comment: Thanks, this is working, but still I need to give for this more bootstrap look

Answer (score 0):

you can use a basic javascript prompt if you want,it will be something like

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
    var prompt = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item");
    if (prompt == true){
       //do the delete function;
    } else {
       //do the alternative function;
    }

    }
</script>
```